# find difference between 2 remote branches

Tags: git

How can I find out what are the differences between 2 remote branches?

I tried:

```
git diff --name-status remotes/branch-V4.4..remotes/branch-V4.2
```

But it gives me a list of files which changes. 
Is there a way I get a list of commits which shows me the difference between 2 branches?

Thank you.

Update:

Thank you for the answer. I have tried 'git log --graph remotes/branch-V4.4...remotes/branch-V4.2'

I see

```
* commit ............
|
|
| 
* commit .............
|
|
| 
* commit .............|
|
| 
* commit .............
```

Why only "|" , a straight line? why it does not show where does the 2 branches begins to diverge?

Thank you.

Comment: I strongly recommend using gitk for rather complicated analyses like this. But if you need to use `git log`, I updated my response with something that will generate a way better output.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably something like:

```
gitk --left-right remotes/branch-V4.4...remotes/branch-V4.2
```

or if gitk is not available:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --left-right --boundary --date-order remotes/branch-V4.4...remotes/branch-V4.2
```

You might also want to try it without the `--date-order`, but especially in complicated situations, I found that `git log` produces more useful graphs with that option.

Every commit in that graph will be either marked with `<`, `>` or `o` - that means that they are part of the left branch, the right branch or a “boundary commit”.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`git log`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) instead of `git diff`:

```
git log remotes/branch-V4.4..remotes/branch-V4.2
```

Comment: `git log remotes/*origin*/branch-V4.4..remotes/*origin*/branch-V4.2`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do.

```
git diff origin/<remote branch>
```

Comment: that will show a diff between the currently checked out branch and that what is locally fetched about the remote.